# white-space css property is creating issues with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing issues with `white-space:nowrap` when there is flex container.

There is a flex `container` with `flex-direction:row;` in which there are two divs `sidebar` with certain width set using `flex:0 0 70px;` and the `main-content`.

In the `main-content` with `flex-direction:column` two main divs, `header` and the `content`.

Now in the `content`, there are three `blade` that has `flex-grow:1`.

Each `blade` has `long-content` that has set `white-space:nowrap`. I want all the three blades to be visible on the screen, that is adjust automatically in the space of `main-content`. But as I have set `overflow-x:hidden;` on the `container` so there will be no horizontal scroll due to this the right screen get cuts, that content is not visible.

I want it to adjust on the screen with equal space of each blade.

Here is the code:

```js
function expand() {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  sidebar.classList.add("sidebar--expanded");

}
```

```css
button {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 70px;
}

.sidebar--expanded {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  background: teal;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.long-content {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.blade {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <button onclick="expand()">Sidebar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="blade">
        <div class="long-content">
          Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add
          title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle
          public.Add title to make the fiddle public.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blade">
        <div class="long-content">
          Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add
          title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle
          public.Add title to make the fiddle public.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blade">
        <div class="long-content">
          Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add
          title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle public.Add title to make the fiddle
          public.Add title to make the fiddle public.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a little tough to explain the whole situation, so here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er_markar/4k1qsm1y/35/).

I have tried all the CSS combination by applying different css rules but not able to achieve it? Please help.

Thanks!!

**Additional Info**
Actually, the second flex-item that is `main-content` is not considering the existence of its sibling that is `sidebar`, so it takes whole screen width considering it as the only item.

Comment: why -ve vote? I have added all the info

Comment: So now I have added the code, so revert the vote?

Comment: I didn't vote but i would hope that others revert theirs.

Comment: There must be rule if you are downvoting the question , you should have to add reason for that

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `content`?

Comment: That's been suggested but shot down **every time**...but with your rep you should know about posting code **in the question**.

Comment: I can't wrap the content :(. blade should adjust

Comment: @Paulie_D , Yeah I should and I know, but I just skipped.

Comment: Well...there you go.

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to both `.main-content` and `.blade`. Explanation is in the duplicate. https://jsfiddle.net/4k1qsm1y/58/

Comment: @Michael_B this solved the issue. but the same problem is with the height. setting min-height is not working but

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to adjust on the screen with equal space of each blade, then why you put white-space: nowrap.
Remove `white-space: nowrap` from the long content and it will automatically adjust within your container taking equal space.

Comment: actually in real scnario there would be table so i dont want to wrap the content.. i have added `overflow-x:auto` it should work properly

Comment: OK then fine... But I don't see that how it work properly. You already use overlfow-x: auto, when you asking that question.

Comment: yes.. but if you set the width of main-content less than the sidebar width it works like less than 90% - so it could be 80%,70% then it works